# apt does not wrok but snap does

Tags: networking, 18.04, apt

The computer is running within a corporate network with a firewall in place. What I don't understand is:

if i run `sudo apt update` I get

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Connection failed [IP: 91.....]
```

on the same machine I can run any `snap` command and install for example `htop`.

Is there a difference between snap and apt the way they communicate with web?
Do you have any idea to enable the connection for apt?

Thanks any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's a network problem , try to check your own network or firewall or other some stuff

Or...you can switch your apt source to another source which is not in blacklist or your firewall